# Use TortoiseGit with multiple GitLab accounts

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, tortoisegit

I have two GitLab account and want to use them with TortoiseGit so for that I made keys and add them to each account so no I have to key in .ssh folder like id_rsa_account1 and id_rsa_account2.
Also I changed config file like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320458/how-to-set-up-two-ssh-keys-for-two-gitlab-accounts-and-push-pull-by-using-tortoi) and now I dont have problem in using git with cmd but I want to use it with TortoiseGit.

Now how can I have two repository like test1 and test2 and use them with TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to set up two SSH keys for two GitLab accounts and push/pull by using TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30320458/3906760) only works if you use OpenSSH.

For using putty plink (which is the default in TortoiseGit) you need to create an alias in putty. You can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183147/3906760

You can also make TortoiseGit use Openssh by setting the ssh client to "ssh" in TortoiseGit network settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an answer 'how to have **multiple accounts with TortoiseGit with different username/password** method (**not with rsa keys**). If you are interested in that method, then checkout the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468061/4036462