# how to switch users in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

There are two Github repositories for which I have been granted access. Both the repository have different credentials.

Some days back, I accessed repository1 using the first set of username & password. Now I am in need to checkout from second respository, but it is taking the first set of username & password for which the access is NOT granted.

So how do I delete the saved credentials?

Already tried with these links.

1. [remove credentials from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)
2. [Remove saved credentials from TortoiseGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782090/remove-saved-credentials-from-tortoisegit)

As I am in need of both the repository, hence I don't want the credentials to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use https URLs you can include the username in the URL using the @-notation (`https://username@github.com/`), then the credentials should be stored for this URL with the username included and not for the whole domain.

or use SSH and PuTTY sessions:

> Start PuTTY, fill in the servername (example.com here) in the Host Name-field and put the servername followed by e.g. a number into the Saved Sessions field (e.g. example.com1 or whatever you like). Go to Connection->SSH->Auth and select the key which should be used for this connection. Now go back to Session and hit Save.
>
> Now, when you want to use this saved session use example.com1 as the servername: Clone git@example.com1:/test.git. Plink detects that this is a saved session and loads the correct servername and ssh key from the session.

Based on https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-faq.html#tgit-ssh-faq-differentkeys and https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html

Also see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183147/3906760
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33609234/3906760