# Git password-less on a distant server with custom SSH port

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit

My situation :

- I have a bunch of folders on my local development machine
- I want to version them on a remote server
- This server uses a custom ssh port (not 22)
- I can do what i need on this server, i have root permissions.
- It doesn't matter if i have to clone empty repos from the server or create local ones and push them. I am free of create/copy/move/delete on the remote and 
  on the local machines.

My problem :

- Can't clone a distant repo or push to one

My goals :

- having a working git server (remote) to hold the repositories
- working the development on my local machine (Windows), uploading it to the remote server on a regular basis

What i did so far :

- created a "git" user on the server
- generated a key pair on my local machine with puttygen
- added the public key to /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
- tested access with putty using the private key : it works
- tried with git with different tools (including tortoisegit) : the login part does not seem to work

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: what remote url are you using on client's side?

Comment: What does `ssh -T <user>@<myserver>` output?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssh://USERNAME@SERVERNAME:PORT/PATH` as URL on the client side. For more detailed PuTTY configuration on client side please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183147/3906760

For the server part there are tutorials such as https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server.

Comment: @MarvinLeRouge please consider to upvote and to accept this answer if it helped you. That is the way to say thank you on stackoverflow.